# Save/load value&color to txt/xml

Tags: c#, colors, save, loading

I'm completely new to C# programming. (4 days)

I did some amateur programming on Excel VB to create an dashboard for our teams. Now I want to lift it to the next level.

My dashboard has 10 buttons changing color from red to green and back each click. Each click changes the label beneath it from Text 1 to Text 2.

Function: overview of the service area who finished work and handed to us.
I got 10 different voids for each of the areas, because I didn't manage to link the clicked button to the label, so I just used 10. "northwest", "east", "southeast" and so on.

```
void northwest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    Control ctrl = ((Control)sender);
    switch (ctrl.BackColor.Name)
    {
        case "Red":
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
            ctrl.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            lbl_nw.Text = "Service";
            break;
        case "LimeGreen":
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
            ctrl.ForeColor = Color.White;
            lbl_nw.Text = "North-West";
            break;
        default:
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
            ctrl.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            lbl_nw.Text = "Service";
            break;
    }
}
```

Second: I got 145 buttons (the teams) changing between 5 different colors each click. We use this to clarify the state of the team. like "n/a", "available", "on the way" etc.

```
void MyButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    Control ctrl = ((Control)sender);
    switch (ctrl.BackColor.Name)
    {
        case "Gainsboro": // switch from n/a to available
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
            ctrl.ForeColor = Color.White;
            break;
        case "LimeGreen": // switch from available to on the way
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            ctrl.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            break;
        case "Yellow": // switch from on the way to fully occupied
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Orange;
            ctrl.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            break;
        case "Orange": // switch from fully occupied to omitted
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
            ctrl.ForeColor = Color.White;
            break;
        case "Red": // switch from omitted to back at home
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            ctrl.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            break;
        default:
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
            ctrl.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            break;
    }
}
```

Now the actual problem: Because my former dashboard can only be used by one person (on one central computer) I wanted to make my new dashboard multi-user friendly.
So my intention is to save the colors/label names into an txt file or xml file (forget about xml. its toooo complex for me) and load it automatically if there were any changes on the board by any user.

I searched but can't find any solution I really understand (because of missing knowledge).

I have tried the following:

```
void save(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\shift.txt");              

    txt.Write(button1.Text);
    txt.Write(button1.ForeColor);
    txt.Write(button1.BackColor);
    txt.Close();
}
```

At this solution I would need to write every button I want to store. Problem: I get something like this:
`North-West Color [LimeGreen] Color [Black]`.

I think the correct solution would be like `North-West;LimeGreen;Black`, but I cant figure out how! Even then I don't know how to load back all values to the correct objects.

And I tried to loop through them with:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 155; i++)
```

But I got problems with the objects (e.g. "is a type but used as an method") every combination.

Second attempt was via xml. But this is way to complex for me.
I tried it like this:

```
void savedata(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet d = new DataSet();
    DataTable t = new DataTable();

    d.Tables.Add(t);
    t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name",typeof(string)));
    t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FontColor",typeof(string)));
    t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Background",typeof(string)));                 
    t.Rows.Add(button6.Text, button6.ForeColor, button6.BackColor);
    t.Rows.Add(button7.Text, button7.ForeColor, button7.BackColor);
    t.Rows.Add(button8.Text, button8.ForeColor, button8.BackColor);
    t.Rows.Add(button9.Text, button9.ForeColor, button9.BackColor);
    t.Rows.Add(button10.Text, button10.ForeColor, button10.BackColor);
    t.Rows.Add(button11.Text, button11.ForeColor, button11.BackColor);
    t.Rows.Add(button12.Text, button12.ForeColor, button12.BackColor);
    t.Rows.Add(button13.Text, button13.ForeColor, button13.BackColor);
    t.Rows.Add(button14.Text, button14.ForeColor, button14.BackColor);
    t.Rows.Add(button15.Text, button15.ForeColor, button15.BackColor);
    d.WriteXml("C:\\Users\\Shift.xml");
}
```

It saves, yes, but how do I load it back into the correct objects?
I don't understand anything about de/serialization, I just read some code and tried to adopt it and failed big.

My question:

Does anyone have a proper solution for the text file how to save/load/format correctly? The save should be done if there is a new change, same goes for the load. So automatically. Every user can open the dashboard, the file storage would be on our server where everyone has access to it to save/load it via dashboard.

I would really appreciate a possible solution for this. Like I said, I'm a beginner and this problem driving me nuts.

Everything works fine, except for the save/load mechanic.

Just to mention:
i cant download any other software, so i need to stick to windows programms.

Answer (score 0):

for saving and loading from a flat file (.txt, .xml, .json, .whatver) I use the following solution, it's honestly very easy and takes the hard work away. You will need to download and install NewtonSoft package from nuget. But trust me it makes everything easy.

Let's create a hypothetical scenario similar to yours. You have many users and want to save information for each of them. Let's start with a user class.

```
public class User {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Theme { get; set; }
}
```

Now lets create a little 'database' or 'data holder' class that will actually store and lookup our info. It will have a FilePath variable where we will save our flat file, a List of all the Users and some functions to help get everything:

```
public static class DataHolder {
        
        public static string FilePath { get; set; }
        public static List<Users> Users { get; set; }
        
        static DataHolder() 
        {
            // Initialize the variables
            FilePath = "C:/Temp/MyData.json";
            Users = new List<User>();
            Init();
        }
        
        static void Init() { }
        
        public static void LoadData() { }
        
        public static void SaveData() { }
}
```

Let's start by creating a file to save all the data in.

```
using System.IO;
using NewtonSoft;
...

static void Init() { 
    // Check if file exists
    if (File.Exist(FilePath))
    {
        LoadData();
        return;
    }
        
    // It doesn't so we create it
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(FilePath)){
        
        // Create empty list of users
        var emptyUserList = new List<User>();
        
        // Convert it into Json using NewtonSoft 
        var fileText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emptyUserList);
        
        // Write it to the file
        sw.Write(fileText);
    }
}
```

Above we used Newton to create a new file with an empty Json object in it. Let's see how loading and saving will work:

```
public static void LoadData() {         
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(FilePath)){
        Users = JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<User>>(sr.ReadToEnd());
    }               
}
        
public static void SaveData() {
    using (var sw = new StreamReader(FilePath)){
        sw.Write(JsonConvert.Serialize(Users));
    }
}
```

And that is the main bulk of the class. Let's implement a `GetUser()` and `AddUser()` function that searches for a user based on Id and then I'll show you an example of how to use the class:

```
    using System.Linq;   
    ...

    public static User GetUser(int id) => Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id = id);
        
    public static void AddUser(User user) => Users.Add(user);
```

Example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args){
    
    // Test the saving
    TestSaving();
    
    // Test the loading
    TestLoading();
    
}

static void TestLoading() { 
    // Get a user
    var loadedUser = DataHolder.GetUser(1);
    
    if (loadedUser != null)
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
    
    
}
static void TestSaving() {
    // Create a new user and add it
    var user = new User() {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Fred",
        Theme = "Red"
    };
    
    // Save the data in memory
    DataHolder.AddUser(user);
    
    // Save the data to file
    DataHolder.SaveData();
}
```